# UiAutomation not connected exception

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso, android-testing, android-uiautomator

i'm doing some test on an Android  app using espresso and uiautomator. When i launch the test via my gitlab CI to do them via wifi i always get this erorr:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
  at android.app.UiAutomation.throwIfNotConnectedLocked(UiAutomation.java:1034)
  at android.app.UiAutomation.waitForIdle(UiAutomation.java:638)
  at android.support.test.uiautomator.QueryController.waitForIdle(QueryController.java:532)
  at android.support.test.uiautomator.QueryController.waitForIdle(QueryController.java:523)
  at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice.waitForIdle(UiDevice.java:621)
  at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice.pressBack(UiDevice.java:352)
  at com.my.app.test.Steps.iPressBack(Steps.java:224)
  at ✽.When I press Back(features/settings.feature:73)
```

the problem is that when i run them locally via AndroidStudio on my machine everything works well, and also on the device logs i don't see anything wrong. I have tried also different phones but same exception.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?